# Flutter: During Login, your app is crashing

Tags: flutter, facebook, flutter-dependencies, facebook-login, flutter-facebook-login

This is what I see while testing my app:

[image]

I got this message recently but I have to say that my code was working fine and I didn't update anything. Facebook support doesn't give any clue and they keep saying that login is not working when they review the app (without any other help).

I use Flutter and this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth
But I don't think code/framework/package is related at all to this issue. Probably more related to the key hash but this is also updated by this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias key -keystore assets/.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

My key hash starts like this:

[image]

But Facebook's "support" shows me this snapshot from its test:

[image]

Why is it different? Is it because I cannot move my app to Live mode?:

[image]

That's because of this:

> We've disabled this app for violating the Facebook Platform Policies.
> You can continue to use it in development mode.

Then, looking into that the problem is this:

[image]

Ok, so the problem is **During Login, your app is crashing**. Fine, but how should I fix it?

Despite I don't think this is related this is my login function:

```
Future facebookSignIn(BuildContext context) async {
    final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

    if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
      final AccessToken accessToken = result.accessToken!;
      AuthCredential credential =
          FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token);
```

// at this point the user is already logged in but I save history in db
await _firebaseCredential(context, credential);
}
}

Comment: Have you been able to fix the problem? I'm in exactly the same situation and I don't know what to do since doing the tests with my development user works fine. Thank you

Comment: About 10" ago I wrote them another email. When appealing I asked a few questions and they just said "sorry but your app doesn't work". I'm considering to remove Facebook from my apps. If the support has no support I'll provide Google as the only network to login

Comment: In case it helps...I have seen that in Google Play Store, in section Setup -> App Integrity -> App Signing appears a Signing Key Certificate that is not the one with which I sign the applications from Android Studio. And when I converted the SHA-1 of this Google certificate to base64...it's exactly the same hash key that facebook testers send me in screenshots saying it doesn't work. So I have added this key hash in the Android section of Facebook and sent an email saying that it already works. I'll let you know if this really fixes the problem.

Comment: already tried that but it didn't work for me. The "support" team only sends me links to read for best practiques and suggests me to open a question in their forum. I did that 2 months ago and I go 0 responses. I told them that I will have to remove Facebook login from my app. I cannot wait for bad reviews

Comment: how did you convert it? Maybe I did it wrong

Comment: I've used this website to convert it: http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en In the Google Play dashboard there are 2 sections: App signing certificate and Upload certificate. I used the SHA1 from the first one and converted it with this website. And that's when I realized that it was the same hash that facebook testers sent me in the screenshot with "Invalid key hash. The key hash Xn...". In my case it worked to add this key to the facebook developers page

Comment: ok, I'll try with this one too

Comment: Hey that actually worked! Feel free to make an answer with that info. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

put the part of your code here, where you using facebook login,
and what is your app state management ?

Comment: added info. As mentioned I don't think this could affect anything because it worked for at least one year without changes

Comment: I also added extra info about the key hash